# Meson dependencies catch22 and lazy access to target output

Tags: generator, meson-build

We ‘d like to introduce Meson to build our existing C++ application. Our structure is as follows:

- Wie have 8 main modules (mod_X)
- Every module has 20-40 subdirs, each with 5 – 100 cpp files; separated in libs and executables.
- `mod_INFRA/apps/myparser` has a target that creates a code generator executable

  - Which depends only on `mod_INFRA/libs/A`
- The code generator must be applied to certain files (*.rules) in numerous subdirs in **all** modules and subdirs, including mod_INFRA itself.
- The generated source code must be compiled and considered with the target in `subdir_X`

**What I’d like to achieve:**

- In `root/meson.build`define a common and re-usable `custom_target` or `generator` that I can invoke/apply in every module and subdir as needed.

**Problem:**

- In `root/meson.build`, we define common variables such as compiler flags etc., and we do `subdir(‘mod_INFRA’)` for each module. In `mod_INFRA/meson.build` I do `subdir(‘apps/xyz’), subdir(‘libs/abc’),` etc. for each subdir. That’s all fine
- However I struggle to define the `custom_target or generator` in `root/meson.build`. The required executable is not yet available before `subdir('mod_INFRA')`. And after `subdir(..)` it is too late, as I need the generator already to build files in other subdirs in `mod_INFRA`.

A possible solution could be a “proxy” that **lazily** resolves the executable by target name. E.g. if I could do (pseudo code): `generator(getTargetOutput(‘myparser’), …)`. But I could not find out if that is available.

Any other thoughts on how to resolve it, without completely restructuring the directory structure?

```
- meson.build
- mod_INFRA
  - meson.build
  - apps
    - meson.build
    - myparser
      - meson.build
  - libs
    - subdir_INFRA_A   (required to build myparser)
      - meson.build
    - subdir_INFRA_B
      - meson.build
    - subdir_INFRA_C    (requires parser to generate code)
      - meson.build
- mod_A
  - meson.build
  - subdir_A_A      (requires parser to generate code)
    - meson.build
  - subdir_A_B      (requires parser to generate code)
    - meson.build
- mod_B
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Somebody suggested: From the top level can you do a subdir straight into "mod_INFRA/libs/subdir_INFRA_A" and "apps/myparser" directories to build them, before returning to the top   level and then subdir down a single level repeatedly thereafter?  That did the trick,